# Rails: elsif && conditional statement in controller action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I am working on a multistep form, which is based on Ryan Bates' [#217 Multistep Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?autoplay=true) tutorial. I needed to implement conditional navigation inside the form and things became quite complex.

Navigation inside the form is working but I have problems with the conditions in my controller relative to the commit.

```
def create
  @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
  if @order.valid?
    if params[:back_button]
      @order.previous_step
    elsif params[:back_button_wiretransfer]
      @order.payment_options_step
    elsif params[:back_button_credit_card]
      @order.creditcard_options_step
    elsif @order.thirdlast_step? && params[:commit] == 'Wiretransfer'
      @order.payment = nil
      @order.payment = 'Wiretransfer'
      @order.confirmation_step
    elsif @order.thirdlast_step? && params[:commit] == 'Credit card'
      @order.next_step
    elsif @order.secondlast_step?
      @order.payment = nil
      @order.payment = 'Credit card'
      @order.next_step
    elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment = 'Wiretransfer'
      ...
    elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment = 'Credit card'
      ...
    else
      @order.next_step
    end
    session[:order_step] = @order.current_step
  end
  if @order.new_record?
    render "new"
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Currently the controller is not able to apply the last two elsif conditions with `@order.payment = 'wiretransfer'` or `@order.payment = 'credit card'`.

All other conditions are working, but when I checkout through the credit card section the wiretransfer part is executed.

When I use:

```
elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment == 'Wiretransfer'
  ...
elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment = 'Credit card'
  ...
```

'Credit card' works, but 'wiretransfer' does not. Since I display the payment attribute on the last step of the form I know it persists at that step although it wasn't saved yet to the database.

What am I doing wrong? I found out that sometimes I have to use `=` and other times `==`, but the rational is not clear to me.

In the view I have to use `==` (comparison) such as in:

```
<% elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment == "Credit card" %>
```

to trigger the right divs.

In the controller the two conditions

```
elsif @order.thirdlast_step? && params[:commit] == 'Wiretransfer' 
elsif @order.thirdlast_step? && params[:commit] == 'Credit card'
```

work only with `==`, while all the others only with `=`. I started by using only `==` in the controller, but when I do so nothing gets executed and new is rendered.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seeing methods like `thirdlast_step?` is kind of concerning. Perhaps there's a better way of expressing this, like steering it towards a `case` to break out step number and `:commit` parameter.

Comment: Yes I am concerned indeed ;0). I didn't refactor yet but only added two steps to see if conditional navigation would work.

Comment: As a note, this tutorial does seem unnecessarily complicated and a fair bit out of date (Rails 3.2?) so take its advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: Looking over this code I'm not sure this is the best approach. You might be better off saving a record that has some kind of "pending" or "incomplete" flag set and kicking that forward between each request, adding data as necessary. The final step flips that flag off, making it "real". This approach seems to be the snowball approach where parameters are accumulated in the views and kicked back and forth each time. That's often a lot messier than having a table with (potentially) incomplete records you need to keep out of scope and invisible until made real.

Comment: Thanks for your advice which I will treasure. I changed the conditional to query the button and now it works. Since it was the last piece I wanted to get everything running first. Now I will start polishing + refactoring look into your suggestion more thoroughly. Thanks again!

Comment: Multi-part forms can be really tricky, but the good news is it's 2019 and you have a lot of client-side tools to help you out. Another thing to consider is to do a lot of the work in JavaScript (e.g. showing and hiding different parts of the form) to avoid the round-trip to the server. You can test intermediate values with AJAX, something Rails handles quite well, if necessary, but client-side validation is often pretty easy too for simple "required" fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `==` in both cases:

```
elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment == 'Wiretransfer'
  ...
elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment == 'Credit card'
  ...
```

`=` assigns a value to a variable, whereas `==` checks if two values/variables are equal.

As `=` returns an assigned value, that is not nil in those two cases it's evaluated as the truth - that's why when you have:

```
elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment = 'Wiretransfer'
```

the next `elsif` is never called.

Worth reading:

- http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/ifelse/#h-2-2
- https://skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/

Comment: This difference might seem minor, but programmers often need to develop an eye for this particular detail as the difference is huge.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Indeed I started with `==` but somehow the second part of the condition is not executed and a new view is rendered.

Comment: `&&` uses something called "short-circuit evaluation", meaning that if the left part of the expression returns `false`, there's no need to evaluate the right part of the expression.

I would make sure `@order.last_step?` is `true`, otherwise `@order.payment` will never be checked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In my last view the same conditional `elsif @order.last_step? && @order.payment == "Wiretransfer"` does work. Only the controller statement somehow does not work ...

Comment: Thanks everyone I learned a lot! I had to change the statement and use a params[:somebutton] now it works and I can start refactoring and improving. I will accept the answer ... although it did not solve my problem completely, it pointed me  into the right direction decisively and is the most sensible thing to say about this chaos ;0). I think that somehow it is not possible to query inside a conditional statement of a controller action for an attribute created in the same action but not yet written to the DB...